# View content of an archive from package without installing it

Tags: apt, package-management, files

I'm trying to find the apache.conf file of the phpmyadmin package to see the contents, but I don't want to install it because I've installed phpmyadmin manually (to solve the mysql-client-5.6 compatibility problem).

I know how to find package contents or file sources (from example, [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/all/phpmyadmin/filelist), or using apt-file), but I don't know how to find the contents of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Debian package:

```
apt-get download phpmyadmin
```

And extract the contents to a folder

```
dpkg -x phpmyadmin_4\%3a4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2_all.deb phpmyadmin_extracted
gedit phpmyadmin_extracted/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Comment: Yes I made a mistake writting it, you can remove the correction know (I did the same in my question).